# Align multiple eqnarray*

Tags: math-mode, align

I am using multiple eqnarray* in one document, but the align doesnt look nice:

```
\begin{eqnarray*}
\bar{x}& = & \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n x_i\\
    & = & \frac{45+60+...+53+65}{10}\\
    & = &\frac{284}{5}\\
\end{eqnarray*}
\subsection{Another one}
Some text and other tings...
\begin{eqnarray*}
    s^2 & = & \frac{1}{n-1} \sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - \bar{x})^2\\
    & = & \frac{1}{9} ((45-57,2)^2+(60-57,2)^2+\dots+(65-57,2)^2)\\
\end{eqnarray*}
```

If you look at the result, you can see that not all the equal signs align equally. The grouping with eqnarray* works, but because we have to insert some other stuff (like subsections), we can't continue the eqnarray* to force all equal signs from both eqnarray* to align the same way. How can we do this?

Comment: note it is strongly recommended to use `align*` not `eqnarray*` although you would have the same issue  here

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I see no reason for aligning unrelated equations in different subsections.

Comment: [Adding multiple paragraphs between aligned equations](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/59768/2417) might help, though I don't know if it works across multiple (sub)sections (or why you would want to do this).

Comment: Other similar questions: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/107033, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/197698 and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/334111

Answer (score 2):

I can think of no convincing reason for aligning unrelated equation structures across sectioning units of the document. However, if you absolutely, positively must perform such an alignment, it *can* be achieved, but only through manual intervention. In the solution provided below, parts of the upper equation are encased in `\parbox` statements, where the widths of the boxes are determined by the longest items to the left and right of the `=` symbols in the lower equation.

As others have already remarked: Don't use `eqnarray` -- it's very badly deprecated, and far-superior alternatives are readily available. Also, don't type `...`; use `\dots` instead.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'align*' environment

\newlength\mylena
% save longest string of second equation block
\newcommand\longstring{\frac{1}{9}((45-57,2)^2+(60-57,2)^2+\dots+(65-57,2)^2)}
\settowidth\mylena{$\displaystyle\longstring$} % measure width of this string

\newlength\mylenb
\settowidth\mylenb{$\displaystyle s^2$} % measure width of this string too

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
\parbox{\mylenb}{\hfill$\displaystyle\bar{x}$} % right-align the material
        &= \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n x_i\\
        &= \frac{45+60+\dots +53+65}{10}\\
\parbox{\mylenb}{}
        &= \parbox{\mylena}{$\displaystyle\frac{284}{5}$}\\
\end{align*}


\subsection{Another one}
Some text and other things \dots 
\begin{align*}
   s^2 &= \frac{1}{n-1} \sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-\bar{x})^2\\
       &= \longstring\\
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```