# Aligning and specifying font size in LaTeX equations

Tags: equations, align

I have specified 3 equation in tex file,

The font size of contents in each equation in the align environment appears to be different.Also, not all equations all aligned in the same way.
Is there a way to specify same font size for all equations and align it in a nice way?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{makecell}

\title{Table}
\author{xx }
\date{May 2019}

\begin{document}

\vspace{1cm}
\large \textbf{1-D   equation:}\\
\begin{align*}
\large{ \hspace{2cm}\frac{\partial A}{\partial t} = 2\frac{\partial A}{\partial x}}
\end{align*}

\large \textbf{Equation 2:}\\
\vspace{1cm}
\small{ \textbf{Number = 2}}\\
\begin{align*}
\large{ X = CS = \frac{R}{8}\Delta G} 
\end{align*}
\vspace{0.5cm}
\large \textbf{Equation 3}\\
\vspace{0.5cm}
\small{ \textbf{Movement}}\\
\begin{align*}
\Large{\hspace{3cm}D_{q} = \frac{\big(\frac{CS}{40}\big)^2.5}{1256}} 
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

EDIT: Updated code after making the changes suggested in the comment. The font
size issue is resolved now. The problem is with the alignment of text and equations.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{makecell}

\title{Table}
\author{xx }
\date{May 2019}

\begin{document}

\vspace{1cm}
\large \textbf{1-D   equation:}\\
\begin{align*}
{\large \hspace{2cm}\frac{\partial A}{\partial t} = 2\frac{\partial A}{\partial x}}
\end{align*}

{\large \textbf{Equation 2:}}\\
\vspace{1cm}
{\small \textbf{Number = 2}}\\
\begin{align*}
\large X = CS = \frac{R}{8}\Delta G
\end{align*}
\vspace{0.5cm}
{\large \textbf{Equation 3}}\\
\vspace{0.5cm}
{\small \textbf{Movement}}\\
\begin{align*}
{\large\hspace{3cm}D_{q} = \frac{\big(\frac{CS}{40}\big)^2.5}{1256}} 
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Commands like `\large` or `\small` don't take an argument, they are switches that make their effect last until the currently active group is closed. Use `{\large ...}` etc. to limit the scope instead.

Comment: There are several other markup problems: 1) You shouldn't use `\\` as newlines, use `\par` or an empty line instead. 2) `align*` is meant to align several equations at a common position, you are only using a single equation each. Perhaps you want `equations` instead? 3) There is a lot of manual spacing. Especially the `\hspace` in the align blocks makes the alignment look weird. For structuring your document, you should better use `\section`, `\subsection` etc. commands and remove the manual spacing.

Answer (score 1):

You should adjust font sizes globally, for example via an option to the document class.  Headings are best done with standard commands for consistency of style and spacing.  You need to issue `\maketitle` to get your title and author printed.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\title{Table}
\author{xx}
\date{May 2019}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section*{1-D   equation:}
\begin{equation*}
  \frac{\partial A}{\partial t} = 2\frac{\partial A}{\partial x}
\end{equation*}

\section*{Equation 2:}
\subsection*{Number = 2}
\begin{equation*}
  X = CS = \frac{R}{8}\Delta G
\end{equation*}

\section*{Equation 3:}
\subsection*{Movement}

\begin{equation*}
  D_{q} = \frac{\bigl(\frac{CS}{40}\bigr)^2.5}{1256}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'd like to know if there a way to align all `=` symbol,in the 3 equations, at the same position.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/197698/15925 (place `&` before `=` instead at the beginning of the line)